# Extracting Function Tags from Parsed Sentence (using Stanford Parser)

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, penn-treebank

Looking at the Penn Treebank tagset (http://web.mit.edu/6.863/www/PennTreebankTags.html#RB) there is a section called "Function Tags" that would be extremely helpful for a project I am working on. I know the Stanford Parser uses the Penn Treebank tagset for its EnglishPCFG grammar so I am hoping there is support for Function Tags.

Using the Stanford Parser and NLTK I have parsed sentences with Clause, Phrase and Word level tags as well as Universal Dependencies, but I have not found a way to get Function Tags from a parsed sentence.

```
parser=StanfordParser(model_path="edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz")
parsed = parser.raw_parse("Jack payed up to 5% more for each unit")
for line in parsed:
    print line
```

Prints out:

```
(ROOT
  (S
    (NP (NNP Jack))
    (VP
      (VBD payed)
      (PRT (RP up))
      (PP (TO to) (NP (QP (CD 5) (NN %) (JJR more))))
      (PP (IN for) (NP (DT each) (NN unit))))))
```

For this example I would like there to be a -EXT (extent) functional tag with the preposition "up to 5% more", though I am unsure of what the actual output would look like.

Is it possible to view the function tags of a parsed sentence using the Stanford Parser and NLTK? If so, how do I accomplish this?

Comment: Please edit your question to show a sample parsed sentence (choose a short one), with a clear explanation of what you want to see from it.

Comment: Edits made. I am unsure of exactly what an output with function tags would look like. My question is primarily a result of failed personal research and to see if anyone knows of any support for function tags with parsers.

Comment: I see. I don't know if the Stanford parser ever emits them, but you can see sentences with such annotations in the Penn treebank corpus itself. E.g., `print(nltk.corpus.treebank.parsed_sents()[10])` (`-SBJ` and `-PRD` tags.).

Comment: From this post: https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/parser-user/2013-February/002256.html , the bottom two notes pertain to function tagging and recommend accessing some hidden parameters. I am using the stanford system in python rather than java (as is in the post), do you have any insights?